# Slider with setTimeout - 'removeClass is not a function error'

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

so I asked a similar question earlier today, but I'm trying to do an upgrade in the code I had. I'm trying to create a slider with a setTimeout function, but I  keep getting the `removeClass is not a function error` on my `jquery` object. Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/intercoder/pen/118bc6426e332eec41b4589022c99c36) with the code

**index.html**

```
<div class=container>
  <img class='isActive' src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> 
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> 
  <img class='isHidden'src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

**index.scss**

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
 display: inline;
 //border: 1px solid white;
}

.slide {

}

.isActive {
  visibility: visible;  
}

.isHidden {
 visibility: hidden; 
}
```

**index.js**

```
$(function() {
  var timer;
  var $allImgItems = $('img');
  var $items = $('.container').find($allImgItems);

  for (let i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
     var $item = $items[i];
   $item.removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive')
                                          /*$item.removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive).setTimeout(function() { $( this ).animate( { scrollLeft: 200 + 'px' } ), '500', 'swing', function() { console.log('Animation completed') } }) */
    console.log(`We are at this item: ${$item}`);    
  }
})
```

Comment: You can replace everything with `$('.container').find('img').removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive');`, there's no  need to loop just to remove and add the same classes, jQuery does that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out how I changed your js function a bit. Seems to work fine now.

```js
$(function() {
  var timer;
  var $items = $('img', '.container');

  for (let i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
     var item = $items[i];
     $(item).removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive');
     console.log(`We are at this item: ${item}`);    
  }
})
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
 display: inline;
 //border: 1px solid white;
}

.slide {
  
}

.isActive {
  visibility: visible;  
}

.isHidden {
 visibility: hidden; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=container>
  <img class='isActive' src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> 
  <img class='isHidden' src="http://placehold.it/350x150"> 
  <img class='isHidden'src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector here

```
var $items = $('.container').find($allImgItems);
```

returns an array of elements, but those elements are not jQuery objects themselves.  After grabbing an element wrap it in `$()` to make it a jQuery object.

```
var $item = $($items[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
  var $items = $('.container').find($allImgItems);
  for (let i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) 
  {
     var $item = $items[i];
```

the $item is an html node not a jquery object, while .removeClass is a jquery object function so you need to change it like this.

```
 $($item).removeClass('isHidden').addClass('isActive')
```